# Intellij: Refactor Change Method Signature to change an abstract method from void to Int, but also add return -1 to all subclasses

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring, return-type, intellij-plugin

Long story short personal project of mine, I am trying to re-do the implementation of something. However, there are many uses of this method and it would take me too much time to do it manually.

Using the change method signature window, I can easily change an abstract method of

```
public abstract void run(int a, int b);
```

to

```
public abstract int run(int a, int b);
```

That part is easy enough and I know how to do it.

However, I'd also like to be add:

Before:

```
@Override    
public void run(int a, int b) {
   /* irrelevant code here */
}
```

After:

```
@Override    
public int run(int a, int b) {
    /* irrelevant code here */
  return -1;
}
```

Is this possible with any of the tools Intellij has to offer?

Comment: Just curious if you have so many methods to refactor that it’s faster to post a question and wait for the answer :D As for the question, you could create an ugly regex pattern to find and replace such methods, don’t know any intellij tools for this

Comment: @vladtkachuk Yes, it's so many that intellij warns me before giving me the results of "find all usages" hehe

Comment: I'd suggest to try the structural search, you can find replace examples here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html

The general guide about structural research: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html#to_search_structurally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of your `irrelevant code` you might be able to get away with using a regex for this.

Something along the lines of:
Find: `(\@Override\npublic void run\(int a\, int b\) \{)(.|\n*?)(^})`
Replace: `$1$2return -1;\n$3`

---

Find explanation:

- `(\@Override\npublic void run\(int a\, int b\) \{)` first part of the method
- `(.|\n*?)` Find any number of any character (including new lines `\n`); non greedy (`?`)
- `(^})` Last/Closing line of the method.

  - Shown here as a line that starts with a closing bracket, but should be changed to match whatever matches the end of your method. Likely four spaces `(^\s\s\s\s})` or a tab `(^\t})`

Replace explanation:

- `$1` first found section
- `$2` second found section
- `return -1;\n` new code to add
- `$3` third found section

Comment: What if there is an “if” statement in the method body?

Comment: Updated the find to use a lazy star (`*?`). This will stop when it finds the next section of the find. Which currently assumes that the closing bracket is the first thing on the line. If you have consistent formatting for this closing line, it can be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @user14301906 Your update works with ignoring any of the closing brackets in the method body but then unfortunately add return null to the final closing bracket of the class

Comment: @Ebp90. I'm not sure what you mean by "add return null to the final closing bracket of the class". Are you saying that it it doesn't get any results? (It seemed to work for me when I tested it with your pseudocode)  
 Have you tried adjusting the closing bracket according to your specific uses? For example, instead of `(^})` you might need `(^    }\n\n)`

Comment: @user14301906 Sorry, I meant that the find regex is finding the whole method I'm searching for but doesn't stop at the end of that method and finds until the closing bracket of the class. Then the replace adds "return -1;" just before the closing brack et of the class.

Comment: @Ebp90 It sounds like you need to adjust the last section of the search. Since your method is inside a class, take the `(^})` part at the end of the search string, and add spaces or tabs, or whatever you use between the start of line symbol `^` and the closing brace symbol `}`. Find one example, copy from the start of the line until the closing brace, and paste it in there. `(^    })`

Comment: @user14301906 Ok, I got it to work, just had to add some spaces like you said. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ebp90 You're welcome. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

@quickfix pointed out a great feature of Intellij that does exactly what you asked for: **Structural Replace**

From the main menu, select **Edit | Find | Replace Structurally** to open the Structural Replace dialog. Then build out the search and replace templates to fit your need.

In your case:

### Search Template:

```
class $Class$ {
  @Override
  public void run (int a, int b) {
      $Content$;
  }
}
```

- `$Class$` has the default $Class$ script modifier: `script=!__context__.interface && !__context__.enum && !__context__.record`
- `$Content$` has the count modifier: `Count=[0,∞]`

### Replace template:

```
class $Class$ {
    @Override
    public int run (int a, int b) {
        $Content$;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

### Screenshot:

[image: Search Replace Screenshot]

---

You can find more details in the jetbrains documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html

There are also examples to help you get started: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html#6a7e67e7